# Why an isLoggedIn observable in a header template is not updated on user login and logout?

Tags: angular, observable

My `AppModule` imports a `CoreModule`

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    LoginService
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {
```

which itself provides a `LoginService` globally.

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.router.navigate(['users']); // TODO Check that all router.navigate don't use hard coded strings
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

    logout() {
        this.authService.logout().subscribe(
            response => {
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

There is also an `AuthService` that does the server side login or logout and that keeps the logged in state in the browser local storage.

```
public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (this.tokenService.accessTokenExpired()) {
    if (this.tokenService.refreshTokenExpired()) {
      return of(false);
    } else {
      return this.refreshAccessToken()
      .pipe(
        map(response => {
          if (response) {
            return true;
          }
        }),
        catchError((error, caught) => {
          return of(false);
        })
      );
    }
  }
  return of(true);
}
```

There is a header template which should display or not depending on the logged in state.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async as isLoggedIn">
```

This header component keeps the logged in state.

```
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isAuthenticated();
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.loginService.logout();
  }
```

The navigation behaves all right but the header template needs a page refresh to be in sync with the logged in state.

It feels like the `isLoggedIn` observable in the header template is not getting updated when the logged in state changes.

The code has been stripped of noise.

EDIT: I work around the issue by skiping the `ngIf` way and usung multiple layouts.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: UsersComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: UserComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        data: {
          expectedRole: 'admin'
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: './views/home/home.module#HomeModule',
        data: {
          preload: true,
          delay: false
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'error',
        component: ErrorComponent
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

A `login` layout:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-layout',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class LoginLayoutComponent { }
```

And a `home` layout:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-layout',
  templateUrl: './home.layout.component.html'
})
export class HomeLayoutComponent { }
```

with its template:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer mode="side" opened role="navigation">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink='/first'>First Component</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink='/second'>Second Component</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Subscribe to $isLoggedIn and check if you are able to get notifications in ts file.

Comment: `isAuthenticated` method sends an http ? or it is a `subject` ?

Comment: @Nour I added the method source code in the question.

Comment: @SunilSingh In which method should I have the subscribe implementation ?

Comment: It seems like you have `changeDetection` problem,, i guess angular did not get change after `logout` get called, so the async pipe did get called. try to add console log in your `isAuthenticated` method. and check if it's get called

Comment: Subscribe on `isLoggedIn$` in the same `ngOnInit` method.

Comment: @Nour I added console loggers and the `isAuthenticated` method is getting called on each navigation event from the `canLoad` method in the `AuthGuardService` service class. But the `isLoggedIn$` observable in the header component is not being updated. Only in the page reload with the `ngOnInit` method, is the `isAuthenticated` being called.

Comment: @SunilSingh I added the following `this.authService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('isAuth: ' + data);
    });` in the `ngOnInit` method but it gets displayed only once, at page load time. It never is displayed on navigation events.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is issue with `isAuthenticated`. It is always returning new `Observable` every time. You should have one `Observable` through which all `Subscription` can be notified.

### AuthService

```
    private authSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    private isLoggedIn$ = this.authSubject.asObservable();

    updateLoggedInState(status: boolean){
        this.authSubject.next(status);
    }

    public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
         return this.isLoggedIn$;
    }
```

### LoginService

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.router.navigate(['users']); // TODO Check that all router.navigate don't use hard coded strings
             this.authService.updateLoggedInState(true);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
                this.authService.updateLoggedInState(false);
            }
        );
    }

    logout() {
        this.authService.logout().subscribe(
            response => {
                this.router.navigate(['login']);
                this.authService.updateLoggedInState(false);
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    }

}
```

> Note : I did not cover token but you can handle it the way you are doing.

Comment: Where do you see more than one observable ?

Comment: In `isAuthenticated()` - `return of(false);` Same for other places too. Everytime it will create new Observable.

Comment: How would you code this if not using any `of(false);` then ?

Comment: `this.authSubject.next(false)`

Comment: Sorry but this `return this.authSubject.next(false); //of(false);` stopped compiling. What is that `authSubject` variable ?

Comment: See my Answer . I have declared `authSubject `